# create event when click next month

Tags: php, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using "fullcalendar" script - 
https://fullcalendar.io/
in order to display tours on calendar

how do i use ajax in order to pull tours data from db about the current/next/previous month.

I just need the code that get the choosen month date (by the user) and run the ajax

```
<div id="calendar"></div>

<script>

          $(document).ready(function() {
            var initialLocaleCode = 'en';

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
              header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
              },

              eventLimit: true, 
              editable: false,

              events: [

                {
                    title: 'tour 1',
                    start: '2019-05-05',
                    end:  '2019-05-11',
                    className: 'bg-warning'
                },{
                    title: 'title for tour num 2',
                    start: '2019-05-19',
                    end:  '2019-05-25',
                    className: 'bg-purple'
                },{
                    title: '3td tour title',
                    start: '2019-05-16',
                    end:  '2019-05-21',
                    className: 'bg-info'
                }   
              ]
            });


          });

</script>
```

Comment: Hello. Can you please clarify, do you need to create event or just get data for current / next/ previous months ?

Comment: Hi @KhurramIshaque - I want to create event that will get the chosen month (full date) and send it to an ajax file

Comment: You should probably not do that by handling click events yourself, but by setting up proper event sources. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

Comment: 04FS is correct, that is the pattern you should follow. fullCalendar will then take care of automatically fetching new events whenever the user moves to a new date. All your server has to do is read the provided start/end dates and return the correct data for that time period. But since you appear to be using version 3 (which is not the newest any more), then ensure you read the correct version of the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function N.B. This option can allow you to implement the same thing more simply as well: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed