# how to alert next month date

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using "fullcalendar" plug- https://fullcalendar.io/ in order to display tours on calendar

when user click next/pre button, how do i ALERT the next/pre full date?

for instant, if the calendar show me the current day (2019-06-03) and i click "next" then alert will display 2019-07-01. clicking "pre" will display 2019-05-01

my code:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>

<script>

          $(document).ready(function() {
            var initialLocaleCode = 'en';

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
              header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
              },

              eventLimit: true, 
              editable: false,

              events: [

                {
                    title: 'tour 1',
                    start: '2019-05-05',
                    end:  '2019-05-11',
                    className: 'bg-warning'
                },{
                    title: 'title for tour num 2',
                    start: '2019-05-19',
                    end:  '2019-05-25',
                    className: 'bg-purple'
                },{
                    title: '3td tour title',
                    start: '2019-05-16',
                    end:  '2019-05-21',
                    className: 'bg-info'
                }   
              ]
            });


          });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd need to do this, since the new date will already be displayed at the top of your calendar.

However, putting that aside, one way to achieve it is to handle the [viewRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/viewRender) event. This will occur anytime either the date range or the type of view is changed on the calendar, and fires just before the new view is actually displayed on the screen. As per the documentation, the view object supplied in the callback contains the the start and end dates which are about to be displayed.

You could write something like this:

```
viewRender: function( view, element )
{
  alert(view.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
}
```

Here's a working demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/8bxqzfev/

Comment: Thanks, but something is not right - the alert date is not the first or the end of the next/pre month

Comment: BTW - i want to catch the next/pre date in order to send the value to ajax file that will pull the relevant data from the DB

Comment: As the [docs explain](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/view-object), the date is the first visible date on the view. Now look again at the "month" view in your calendar. You'll easily see that (in order to maintain the shape of the grid) the 1st of the month is rarely the first visible date. But that first date will be the one you see in the alert. Again if you [read the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/showNonCurrentDates) you can also see that you can switch this behaviour off. Here's a demo where it does more like what you expected: http://jsfiddle.net/cezsh4Lp/

Comment: And... "i want to catch the next/pre date in order to send the value to ajax file that will pull the relevant data " ...as per the comments you received on your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422777/create-event-when-click-next-month), this is not the correct way to do it in fullCalendar. fullCalendar provides this kind of functionality **automatically** if you follow the links we gave you there and implement it like that. You just give fullCalendar a URL or function, and it will run that code whenever the view changes.

Comment: Did you even read those links you were given earlier? You never responded to it. Instead you asked this question instead, and ignored the advice. I strongly suggest you [read about it properly](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-data). Read, read, read and read again, and also look at the demos (all of which have source code available to use as an example). Almost everything you could think of is already explained, either in the documentation or in older questions on this site. You just need to take the time to look at it.

Comment: P.S. If you read it, make a serious attempt to implement the event AJAX functionality as per one of the suggested patterns, and then get stuck with a specific issue, you can of course ask a new question about it, and we will happily help you. In the meantime there is no point in us guiding you to implement a solution which is not optimal.

Comment: showNonCurrentDates  wasn't valid in my plug version. now it's working. thanks...

Comment: i tried the code of section "jQuery $.ajax options" on the website (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed) but i always get the message "there was an error while fetching events!" so it's not working for me...

Comment: Well there could be lots of possible reasons for that generic message. Clearly it can and does work, or else it wouldn't be documented. So you need to find out specifically what went wrong for you. Probably it's a server-side error, or a mistake in your ajax config. You need to do some debugging. If you'd like help from me about it, ask a new question on StackOverflow and include client- and server-side code, and info from your browser console and/or network tab, and/or server-side error logs, as appropriate, so that I have a chance of understanding and even reproducing your specific issue.

Comment: just ant to thank you - i tried again to work with ajax and it's working fine now....so - thank you :)